# BT clients doesnt return token to get_peer as specified

Tags: protocols, bittorrent, dht, kademlia

I'm trying to implement a program that able to communication to the mainline kademlia protocol
I had follow the specification here http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html

when i perform the get_peer query to a random node of internet
it suppose to return a write token but no matter how many node i try
the write token is missing

sample data I sent:

d1:ad2:id20:-WP0001-4145477439689:info_hash20:-WP0000-5555555555556:noseedi1ee1:q8:get_peer1:v4:WPvA1:t2:aa1:y1:qe

nodes I had try: 
lots of random nodes obtain by using find_node query, bootstrap node is router.bittorrent.com

I do get a list of nodes in return, everything is normal except the token is missing

is there any rule i must follow in order to obtain the token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **s** in `get_peers` are missing.

Your sample:

`d1:ad2:id20:-WP0001-4145477439689:info_hash20:-WP0000-5555555555556:noseedi1ee1:q`**8:get_peer**`1:v4:WPvA1:t2:aa1:y1:qe`

should be:

`d1:ad2:id20:-WP0001-4145477439689:info_hash20:-WP0000-5555555555556:noseedi1ee1:q`**9:get_peers**`1:v4:WPvA1:t2:aa1:y1:qe`